# ggplot: Dual y-axis, how to fix the left y-axis range and breaks?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
# Create sample data
df <- data.frame(
  ID = rep(10002, 25),
  Day = c(-11, -10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13),
  Score1 = c(2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 2, 4, 4, 4),
  Score2 = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4),
  Score3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  Score4 = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5),
  Score5 = c(0, 1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3),
  Score6 = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5),
  Score7 = c(2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4),
  Score8 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  DASTWT = c(204, 206.4, 209, 209.6, 212, 202, 204, 204.6, 206.2, 208.2, 208.8, 197.6, 202.4, 204.2, 208.4, 209.6, 209.4, 211.6, 213, 201, 202.4, 206.4, 206.6, 208.2)
)
```

I wrote the following code to make a line graph with 2 y-axes:

```
coeff <- 40

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Day)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Score1, color = "Score 1")) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1, linetype="dashed", color = "grey", size = 0.5) + 
  scale_y_continuous(
    limits = c(0, 5),
    breaks = seq(0, 5, by = 1),  
    labels = seq(0, 5, by = 1)
    ) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    limits = c(-14, 14),  # Set the limits for the x-axis
    breaks = seq(-14, 14, by = 2),  # Set the tick locations
    labels = seq(-14, 14, by = 2)   # Set the tick labels
  ) +
  geom_line(aes(y = DASTWT/coeff, color = "Weight")) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Score 1", sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*coeff, name = "Weight")) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "green")) +
  labs(x = "Day") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    axis.title.y = element_text(color = "red", vjust = 2),
    axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "green", vjust = 2),
    legend.position = "none"
  )
```

When `y = Score1`, the left y-axis label shows only 0, 2,and 4. But when I ran `y = Score2`, the left y-axis label shows only 1 to 5 (**no zero shown**). What's even worse is that, when I ran `y = Score6`, the left y-axis only shows 4 and 5.

My question is, how can I standardize all the figures produced with `y = Score1 - 6`, with the left y-axis **consistently shows 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5**?

Comment: Remove the second scale_y_continuous, i.e. use `scale_y_continuous(breaks=..., labels = ..., limits = ..., sec.axis= ..., name = ...)` in the first. Otherwise the second scale_y_continuous overwrites the breaks and limits set via the first.

Comment: That worked, thank you